# Exception while trim all string properties in a object - Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Here is my code where i am getting error : "Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true."

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomInfo obj = new CustomInfo();
        var stringProperties = obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                      .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));

        foreach (var stringProperty in stringProperties)
        {
            string currentValue = (string)stringProperty.GetValue(obj, null);
            stringProperty.SetValue(obj, currentValue.Trim(), null);
        }
    }

}

public class CustomInfo
{
    int UserId { get; set; }
    string UserName { get; set; }
    string Country { get; set; }
    string City { get; set; }
    DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    bool isActiveUser { get; set; }

}
```

I am unable to Trim all string properties in a object.

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't demonstrate the problem. (I've just put it into a console app, and it works fine.)

Comment: Hi Jon,I executed this code but it's not returning the property info of string & i checked obj.GetType() is throwing me the error.

Comment: Please show the full stack trace.

Comment: @user2752023: I suspect you're executing *similar* code in a different project. As I say, the exact code you've given is fine.

Comment: This is simple one page windows form application and i am getting -  [System.InvalidOperationException] {"Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true."} System.InvalidOperationException.i am quite new but i am not sure how this is working from your end.

Answer (score 0):

The code you show executes the `foreach` loop zero times because your properties are non-public.

If you fix that, you get instead a `null` reference exception because you read a `null` string from the property getter and then calls `Trim()` on `null`.

There appears to be no more problems than these with the code you presented. Update your question if you want help on some other code.